# Are these 2 groups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am struggling to find out whether these 2 groups are isomorphic or not. In general what should be the steps to find out?

$$G = (\mathbb{Z}_6,+), \quad H = (\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3, +)$$

Comment: You could start by writing down (for both groups) all elements and their orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case, use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b \cong \mathbb{Z}_{ab}$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. You have $a = 2$, $b = 3$ and $\gcd(2,3) = 1$.